# Looking for a special way to join on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join

I would like to join two tables but couldn't find any existing joins(I tried left, right, full, cross) to do that.
I want to combine table 1 and table 2 into the table 3. 
The data order was based on chronological order, and I would like to see the same order in desired table.

TABLE 1:

Student----   Score1
A------------        90
A------------         80
B------------        85
B------------        60
C------------         50
C------------         40

Table2:

Student----   Score2
A------------ 66
A------------        70
A------------        85
B------------        60
C------------         40

Table 3: Desired Table

Student----   Score1-----Score2
A------------        90 ----------- 66
A------------         80 ----------- 70
A------------null  -----------85
B------------        85 ----------- 60
B------------        60 ----------- null
C------------         50 ----------- 40
C------------         40 ----------- null

Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208743/discussion-on-question-by-william-t-looking-for-a-special-way-to-join-on-sql-ser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we need as first thing try to find a way to add a positional column to your table at runtime. This can be done with ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Student) Position FROM Table1

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Student) Position FROM Table2
```

This creates a nice Position column in our result:

```
Student    Score1      Position
---------- ----------- --------------------
A          90          1
A          80          2
B          85          1
B          60          2
C          50          1
C          40          2

(6 rows affected)

Student    Score2      Position
---------- ----------- --------------------
A          66          1
A          70          2
A          85          3
B          60          1
C          40          1

(5 rows affected)
```

Now we need to join these two temporary results. Since you want to include all the rows from each table, leaving empty (NULL) the spaces left from non-matching rows. `FULL OUTER JOIN` comes to the rescue, in all its beauty:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Student) Position FROM Table1) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Student) Position FROM Table2) T2 
    ON T1.Student = T2.Student AND T1.Position = T2.Position
```

We get this:

```
Student    Score1      Position             Student    Score2      Position
---------- ----------- -------------------- ---------- ----------- --------------------
A          90          1                    A          66          1
A          80          2                    A          70          2
NULL       NULL        NULL                 A          85          3
B          85          1                    B          60          1
B          60          2                    NULL       NULL        NULL
C          50          1                    C          40          1
C          40          2                    NULL       NULL        NULL

(7 rows affected)
```

Now just select what you are interested in:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.student, T2.student) Student,
       T1.score1,
       T2.score2
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Student) Position FROM Table1) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Student) Position FROM Table2) T2 
    ON T1.Student = T2.Student AND T1.Position = T2.Position
```

And voilà:

```
Student    score1      score2
---------- ----------- -----------
A          90          66
A          80          70
A          NULL        85
B          85          60
B          60          NULL
C          50          40
C          40          NULL

(7 rows affected)
```

Be aware though: with many records, this could not be the most efficient way of storing and retrieving your data...

**Edit: what follows has been added after answer acceptance**

**Really important**: since a small diatribe is born in comments, let's state the obvious.

The database design proposed by OP has many defect, for first it's based on the assumption that the order of the records in the table will always be the one in which the records have been inserted.

*This could not be true and my solution can not work as expected until some more robust way of sorting records is implemented.*

Would it be better to add a `CreatedAt` column to both tables, of type `datetime`, in which to store record insert date:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD
    CreatedAt datetime NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Table1_CreatedAt DEFAULT getdate()

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2 ADD
    CreatedAt datetime NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Table2_CreatedAt DEFAULT getdate()
```

This could allow to more safely order the records.

The solution would change as follows:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.student, T2.student) Student,
       T1.score1,
       T2.score2
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY CreatedAt) Position FROM Table1) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY CreatedAt) Position FROM Table2) T2 
    ON T1.Student = T2.Student AND T1.Position = T2.Position
```

Comment: The score order per group is apparently not based on sorting but on some notion of input order but since tables are unordered the functionality they want--which they do not explain--is not possible. Unclear questions should be closed & downvoted, not answered. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Comment: @philipxy I was perplexed too from the database design, but my solution clearly demostrates that it is possible, although illogic in real world. Question explains enough for the solution to be found, and IMHO we do not have to know the reasons behind one question unless they are needed for solving. I have converted images to text.

Comment: It is coincidental the the order happened to come out as desired. PS Thanks for the text.

Comment: @philipxy Yes it is, probably phisical record order helps in this case. I've already suggested to add a datetime column over which to ORDER BY, that would improve both DB design and solution stability, IMO.

Comment: Your code doesn't accomplish what you are guessing is being asked. So it's not appropriate to say that it does.

Comment: @philipxy let's agree to disagree :) (also I tried this on an actual Sql Server, with data provided by OP, I've clearly stated that DB design has flaws, provided design improvement advice, I think WilliamT got the point)

Comment: @philipxy The data entry was based on chronologically entry order. I've updated that earlier. Thanks.

Comment: So much for "I think WilliamT got the point". Also see my comments on the question. Bye now.

Comment: Hi. Please do not unjustly criticize my comments by calling them a ["diatribe"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/diatribe).

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically:

```
with t1 as (
    select    *, ord = row_number() over(partition by student order by score1 desc)
    from      table1 
),

t2 as (
    select    *, ord = row_number() over(partition by student order by score2)
    from      table1 
)

select    student = isnull(t1.student, t2.student),
          t1.score1,
          t2.score2
from      t1
full join t2 on t1.student = t2.student and t1.ord = t2.ord;
```

But I doubt your desire is to order scores in table1 in descending order and scores in table2 in ascending order.  So you're going to have to pin that down.  Is there a column for time the test was administered?  Probably best to order by that.

Better still, do this in your front end software, such as with SSRS, crystal reports, or the like.  I say this because I assume this is for a reporting need where the rows don't really represent 'records' anymore.

Comment: The score order per group is apparently not based on sorting but on some notion of input order but since tables are unordered the functionality they want--which they do not explain--is not possible. Unclear questions should be closed & downvoted, not answered.